# How to create a dummy Controller in Command Shell pass to Component CakePHP 2.4.3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.4, cakephp-2.x

I use CakePHP 2.4.3

My code in Command Shell PhulyShell.php

```
<?php
App::uses('ComponentCollection', 'Controller');
App::uses('HopeeComponent', 'Controller/Component');

class PhulyShell extends AppShell {

    public $components = array('Hopee');

    public function initialize() {
        $collection = new ComponentCollection();
        $this->Hopee = new HopeeComponent($collection);
    }
}
```

HopeeComponent.php was previously written by someone else, I have no right to edit it.
Inside the file it has a piece of code

```
public function __construct(ComponentCollection $collection, $settings = array()) {
     if($this->_Controller->request != null){
        $shortcut_app_flag = $this->_Controller->request->query('phuly_app');
     }
}
```

It will throw an error because there is no controller **$this->_Controller**

```
Notice Error: Trying to get property of non-object in [cakephp-2.4.3/phuly/Controller/Component/HopeeComponent.php, line 112]
```

I know one solution is to pass a controller to it

```
<?php
App::uses('ComponentCollection', 'Controller');
App::uses('HopeeComponent', 'Controller/Component');
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
App::uses('TestController', 'Controller');

class PhulyShell extends AppShell {

    public $components = array('Hopee');

    public function initialize() {
        $collection = new ComponentCollection();
        $collection->init(new TestController);
        $this->Hopee = new HopeeComponent($collection);
    }
}
```

It works and no show Notice Error, but I don't want to create a file **TestController.php**, I cannot use **AppController.php**

Is there a way to pass a dummy Controller to the Component **without** creating a file Controller in Shell Command?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: That's really not how you should do it. Tell whoever is saying that you are not allowed to edit the file, that they are wrong in enforcing such restrictions, as it will result in you having to write bad code. If you need to use the same code in a component, and in a shell command, then you should move that code into a separate service that both layers can use!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer by myself, just using Controller, I'm dumb for not noticing this

```
   <?php
    App::uses('ComponentCollection', 'Controller');
    App::uses('HopeeComponent', 'Controller/Component');
    App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');
    
    class PhulyShell extends AppShell {
    
        public $components = array('Hopee');
    
        public function initialize() {
            $collection = new ComponentCollection();
            $collection->init(new Controller);
            $this->Hopee = new HopeeComponent($collection);
        }
    }
```